# Can we use getcontext in linux to get the context of an another thread?

Tags: c, multithreading

I am trying to understand the `getcontext` and `setcontext` linux API.
currently `getcontext` can be used to get the context of its own thread.
and I wanted to know whether it can also get the context of an another thread.

Comment: Please edit your question by adding an entire paragraph motivating it

Answer (score 1):

> can we use getcontext in linux to get the context of an another thread?

**You cannot get the context of another running thread**, since that thread is probably running on some other [processor core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor) (so its context is of course changing, since it contains the [processor registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register) of that other thread).

Read much more about [operating systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) and [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). Read also more about the [Linux kernel scheduler](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/scheduler/index.html) and a [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).

See also [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html), [futex(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/futex.7.html), [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html), [nptl(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/nptl.7.html), [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html), [tgkill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/tgkill.2.html) and [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) (the [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) used by [pthread_create(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) to start threads).

You might but should not use low level [ptrace(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) facilities. I tend to believe that a thread might trace another thread of the same process (see [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)...), but I am not sure, and if you did that, your program becomes very brittle (prone to [heisenbugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug)).

I believe that [setcontext(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setcontext.3.html) and **`getcontext` should *not* be used in multi-threaded programs**.

Study the source code of an existing standard C library such as [musl-libc](https://musl-libc.org/) or GNU [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/). Use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html).